# Reusing the same instance of SHA256CryptoServiceProvider

Tags: c#, .net

Is there any problem with reusing 1 instance of `SHA256CryptoServiceProvider` for the whole AppDomain (and dispose it only at the end)? Or is it better to recreate it and dispose it before each hash? I bet to create it only once will be quicker, but can we do it? In other words, in the example below is there any documentation showing which approach is better / more appropriate? Function `GetHash` (which recreates & disposes CSP every single time) or `GetHash2` (which uses 1 single static instance and reuses it always).

```
public static class Helper
{
    public static string GetHash(string input)
    {
        using (var hashAlgorithm = new SHA256CryptoServiceProvider())
        {
            var byteValue = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);

            var byteHash = hashAlgorithm.ComputeHash(byteValue);

            return Convert.ToBase64String(byteHash);
        }
    }

    static readonly SHA256CryptoServiceProvider _hashAlgorithm2 = new SHA256CryptoServiceProvider();
    public static string GetHash2(string input)
    {

        var byteValue = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);
        byte[] byteHash;
        lock (_hashAlgorithm2)
        {
            byteHash = _hashAlgorithm2.ComputeHash(byteValue);
        }
        return Convert.ToBase64String(byteHash);

    }

}
```

Comment: Why are you asking us, [go race your horses](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/) and find out which is faster to do.

Comment: Because the question is not only about the speed @ScottChamberlain. I bet calling `new` once is quicker that calling `new` many times, isn't it? The SHA256CryptoServiceProvider is a CSP which is supposed to be disposed. Can I just keep reusing it or should I dispose it as soon as possible or is there any security concern using only one instance in the entire application? Whenever it comes to security I tend to be paranoid and MSDN is not very helpful in this case.

Comment: Well, you never asked any of those security concerns in your question, all you said was "*Is there any significant performance penalty for creating & disposing SHA256CryptoServiceProvider for each hash?*" which the answer to that is "Can't say without running it in place with your data set, there are performance penalties for both methods that vary based on the the amount of contention for the lock" and various forms of a vague "Which is better?"". [Update your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34118886/edit) to be about security conserns if you want to know about security conserns.

Comment: Thanks @ScottChamberlain, I updated the question. It's not only security, maybe there can be some memory use. I don't know and I cannot find any "best practices" or at least some examples how to use this on MSDN.

Comment: Without having validated it, this blog indicates that it is NOT safe to reuse an SHA256-instance due to lack of thread safety https://wanderingdeveloper.medium.com/c-cautionary-tail-the-dangers-of-sha256-reuse-2b5bb9c6fde9